# Fetch Unique Document in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, unique-key

Sample Data:

```
    {"_id" : ObjectId("58bd10e4ff1743c527754160"),
        "data" : [
            {
                "No" : "70",
                "Type" : "82",
                "Device" : "01",
                "timestamp" : "2017-03-06 13:00:32"
                }]
   },
   {"_id" : ObjectId("58bd10sdfe4ff1743csdf0754"),
        "data" : [
            {
                "No" : "75",
                "Type" : "22",
                "Device" : "02",
                "timestamp" : "2017-03-06 13:00:32"
                }]
   }
```

I have some document which having same timestamp,so I want to find only unique document on the basis of timestamp.
I have done distinct of timestamp but I want full document.

desired Output:
If same timestamp is there I want only One document.

Answer (score 1):

```
You will only get one output if you run this query.

db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([{$match:{"data.timestamp":"2017-03-06 13:00:32"}},{$limit:1}])
```

Comment: thnaks, now i want to delete duplicate one.

Comment: Use the same aggregate function to get one result document and then use remove function to delete that document.@TB.M

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([  
   {  
      $group:{  
         _id:"$data.timestamp",
         data:{  
            $first:"$data"
         }
      }
```

}
])

This will give you following :

```
{ "_id" : [ "2017-03-06 13:00:32" ], "data" : [ { "No" : "70", "Type" : "82", "Device" : "01", "timestamp" : "2017-03-06 13:00:32" }, { "No" : "10", "Type" : "20", "Device" : "01", "timestamp" : "2018-02-04 10:00:00" } ] }
```

Solution 2 :

```
db.your_collection.aggregate([ 
    { $unwind : '$data'}, 
    { $group : { 
        _id : '$data.timestamp', 
        'No': { $first : '$data.No'},
        'Type': { $first : '$data.Type'},
        'Device': { $first : '$data.Device'},
        'timestamp': { $first : '$data.timestamp'},
        }
    } 
]);
```

This will give you following :

```
[
    { "_id" : "2017-03-06 13:00:32", "No" : "70", "Type" : "82", "Device" : "01", "timestamp" : "2017-03-06 13:00:32" },
    { "_id" : "2018-02-04 10:00:00", "No" : "10", "Type" : "20", "Device" : "01", "timestamp" : "2018-02-04 10:00:00" },
]
```

Comment: thanks a alot and whatever is duplicate how to remove that?